# Automatically add row in ng-grid when tabbing past last cell

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am building an Excel-like data entry form.  Its designed to help our data entry clerks rapidly transcribe information from paper forms that are filled-in by hand.  I am using AngularJS and ng-grid for the presentation and data layer, but I'm getting stuck on one last requirement.

Basically, when the user tabs past the last cell on the last row, I want a new row to be automatically added.  I've tried trapping the `afterSelectionChange` event, but that doesn't seem to be firing, since I'm not actually changing the row at the end.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to use beforeSelectionChange to add a new row when the last row is selected.

http://plnkr.co/edit/mmJFyl?p=preview

```
// main.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$log) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
      data: 'myData' ,
      enableCellEdit:true,
      enableCellSelection:true,
      beforeSelectionChange:function(a1){
        if(a1.rowIndex===$scope.myData.length-1){
          $scope.myData.push({name:"new",age:"0"});
        }
        return true;
      }
    };
});
```